# html+css+js combination not working correctly within Google Chrome or Safari browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Disclaimer: This is a question from a 'python coder learning jQuery'.

I have the following simple html structure (filename: index.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>astrobox.io | Welcome!</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/Users/iMacHome/astroboxio/script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Users/iMacHome/astroboxio/stylesheet.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="panel">
            <br />
            <br />
            <p>Welcome!</p>
        </div>
        <p class="slide"><div class="pull-me">astrobox.io</div></p>
    </body> 
</html>
```

This links to the following .js script (filename: script.js):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.pull-me').click(function(){
        $('.panel').slideToggle('slow')
    });
});
```

And just for completeness, here is my .css file (filename: stylesheet.css):

```
body {
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    width:800px;
    text-align:center;
}

.pull-me{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 8px #562cd4;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #562cd4;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #562cd4;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.panel {
    background: #000000;
    background-size:90% 90%;
    height:380px;
    display:none;
    color:#ffffff;
    font-family:basic,arial,sans-serif;
}
.panel p{
    text-align:center;
}
.slide {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border-top:solid 2px #562cd4;
}
.pull-me {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    right:-25px;
    width:150px;
    height:20px;
    font-family:basic,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    color:#ffffff;
    background:#562cd4;
    text-decoration:none;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
}
.pull-me p {
    text-align:center;
}
```

Now, I have all three of these scripts all within the same directory and upon opening the index.html file into safari and Google chrome, the toggle down functionality does not work. It worked on testing...

Can anyone perhaps shed some light as to why this could possibly be happening. Better still, if you can spot the problem or why it isn't working that would be excellent.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to include jQuery

Comment: Ah yes, within my development environment this library is already installed. I will try this!

Comment: With all of the suggested edits, it is still not loading locally in my Safari or Google Chrome browsers...

Comment: Works fine in the fiddle with jQuery included : http://jsfiddle.net/r0oq26bd/

Comment: I'm using jsfiddle too. Works there fine. Just not locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have added jquery or you have the right script order(first jquery then your scripts).
for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Users/iMacHome/astroboxio/script.js"></script>
```

If you forget to include jquery scripts or libraries using jquery will not work

Comment: Hi Manos, I have included this as you say, however it is still not working. Could you try testing it on your machine locally?

Comment: You have to use the order i used.First jquery link then your scripts.Also i tried it in local machine and it is working

Comment: Excellent! Order is everything! jQuery before js script. Thankyou.

Answer (score 2):

<del>It isn't possible to tell exactly why it isn't working - but I'd bet my bottom dollar it's the lack of a semicolon on this line:</del>

<del>`$('.panel').slideToggle('slow')`</del>

<del>Try checking the console for errors.</del>

EDIT:

It looks like you forgot to include jQuery. Add the script into your `<head>`, before your jQuery dependent script(s):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Downvoters.. please suggest improvements or explain what you think is wrong with my answer?

Comment: Will try this, console gives off 0 errors. Only one warning in the css

Comment: Here's a good explanation as to when they're optional: http://www.codecademy.com/blog/78-your-guide-to-semicolons-in-javascript

Comment: @ZeRubeus As I just said, I didn't know that they were optional (in some cases).

Comment: @Billy you owe us your bottom dollar... :)

Comment: @michael I *would* have bet my bottom dollar - I'm glad I didn't! ;)

Comment: @Billy it's good to learn when they are optional! I think for good measure I will include all ;

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to provide full paths to your files but you need to include jQuery first

Change this part:

```
<head>
    <title>astrobox.io | Welcome!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Users/iMacHome/astroboxio/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Users/iMacHome/astroboxio/stylesheet.css"></link>
</head>
```

to

```
<head>
    <title>astrobox.io | Welcome!</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css"></link>
</head>
```

I have added the google cdn, but you can also include jquery by linking to your local copy.

Comment: I tried both the abridged and full versions. Would I need to somehow load in jQuery to the index.html file?

Comment: Yes you do, @MichaelRoberts I've added a link to google's cdn